# SQL database failing to initialise on second PC with message 'The underlying provider failed to open'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have a VSExpress 2013 solution (with 3 projects) with Entity Framework (ADO.NET) accessing a SQL Server database. I am able to publish my project to the original source PC, and it works as expected, but attempting to install on a second PC via CD fails. The installation is failing to instantiate or create the necessary database files on the local SQL Server (localDB), although SQL Server Express (LocalDB) installs correctly.

I tried adding the line:

```
Database.SetInitializer<PMMEntities>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PMMEntities>());
```

to `MainWindow()` on start-up to initialise the database. However, I still get the following error on running the application on the other PC:

> A network-related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or was not accessible.  Verify that the the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces. error:26 - Error locating Server/Instance Specified)

The connection string in `app.config` is (note that I am not trying to access a shared database on a network, and each installation on another PC must create and run its own local DB):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PMMEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/PMMData.csdl|res://*/PMMData.ssdl|res://*/PMMData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PMM;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am using ClickOnce settings. What do I need to do to achieve effective installation on other PCs so that they will instantiate a new database on first execution?

Comment: Is SQL Express installed on the second PC?  If it's part of the ClickOnce deployment, can you verify that that part of the deployment is working?  Sounds like SQLExpress either isn't installed or isn't installed with instance name "SQLEXPRESS".

Comment: @wablab Yes.  The instal log reports the following at the end of checking for SQL Server:    'SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Launching Application.
Application appears to be an application manifest
Launching application manifest via dfshim
LaunchApplication failed with HRESULT '-2147221164'
Running command 'D:\PMM.wpfUserInterface.application' with arguments ''
ShellExecuteEx failed with error code 87
Error: The following error occurred attempting to install 'D:\PMM.wpfUserInterface.application':
"The parameter is incorrect. "

Comment: @wablab Solved.  You were correct - I was installing SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB and not SQL Server 2012 Express.  Not sure the significance, but the .exe was not able to initiate on the LocalDB version of SQL Server. All now good, thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I added my comment as an answer so that you can accept it to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like SQL Express is not installed on the second PC, it's being installed with a different instance name, or the installation is failing during the ClickOnce deployment.